# Put another collection as the values of "WHERE ... IN (...)"

Tags: mysql, collection, sql, query

I have three collections and want to find out the mutually existing record between them according to one of the column. My current solution is to put another collection to "IN" in the query, like:

```
$second_collection = $model->getCollection()
                           ->addFieldToFilter("in"=>$another_collection);
```

However, the value returned by $another_collection->getData() is not an acceptable array to "addFieldToFilter" function. So I use "another_collection->getColumnValues('field')" to return an array. But 500 internal server error occurs. How can I do?

Code of getting collection:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('model/table');
$first_collection = $model->getCollection()
                         ->addFieldToSelect('target_field')
                         ->addFilter('filter_field', $filter_value1);
$second_collection = $model->getCollection()
                         ->addFieldToSelect('target_field')
                         ->addFilter('filter_field', $filter_value2)
                         ->addFieldToFilter('target_field', 'in'=>$first_collection->getColumnValues('target_field'));
$third_collection = $model->getCollection()
                          ->addFieldToSelect('target_field')
                          ->addFilter('filter_field', $filter_value3)
                          ->addFieldToFilter('target_field', 'in'=>$second_collection->getColumnValues('target_field'));
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `$another_collection->getSelectSql(true)` or `$another_collection->getSelect()`. Be sure that `$another_collection` have only one column

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It does not work. Internal server error still occurs.

Comment: can you add the error, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The First problem is in method `addFieldToFilter`

```
addFieldToFilter('target_field', 'in'=>$second_collection->getColumnValues('target_field'));
```

must be

```
addFieldToFilter('my_field', ['in' => 'my_condition'])
```

The second parameter must be an array

You can add a SQL query in IN with something like this:

```
addFieldToFilter('my_field', ['in' => new Zend_Db_Expr($collection->getSelectSql(true))])
```